# Kohana URL rewriting

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, kohana

I've installed Kohana and there is a problem appear, when I started to edit Kohana::init and .htaccess to make it work with no '/index.php/'

Here is what I'm doing.

My OS is Ubuntu linux 10.04

I've changed Kohana::init 'base_url' param to '/kohana/' and on .htaccess RewriteBase is the same

Also added 'index_file => '' on Kohana::init

But now it is not working

It works for http://localhost/kohana/

but do not works for http://localhost/custom/change

however, it still works for http://localhost/index.php/custom/change

Maybe .htaccess do not work at all? On Ubuntu files that starts from (.) point become hidden. and it is now hidden.

So I spent 2 hours trying to fix it, but still do not know where is the problem.

Will be happy, if someone here can spend his time trying to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Apache httpd.conf/vhost.conf for AllowOverride All, else .htaccess files won't be read. It's disabled per default. (Nobody knows why.)

Otherwise post your RewriteRule set. Else it's just guessing.

Comment: that helped me, but the problem was not only in it. I've checked Apache error log, and found here that mod_rewrite isn't work correct. That was because it was not uploaded to mods folder.