# Remove "/index/" from URIs in Kohana 3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

As of right now all of my controllers are mapped like this:

- `http://example.com/index/index`
- `http://example.com/index/services`
- `http://example.com/index/contact`

What I want to do is change the configuration of the URI to look like this:

- `http://example.com/index`
- `http://example.com/services`
- `http://example.com/contact`

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

My `bootstrap.php` has the following:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/',
    'index_file' => FALSE
));
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135594/kohana-urls-including-index-on-redirects-and-pagination

Comment: Do you mean `http://example.com/index.php/index`? Or you have `Controller_Index` with different actions and want to skip controller name in URL?

Answer (score 3):

Your .htaccess code looks fine. Check that your Apache configuration is fine:
[Kohana URL rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689822/kohana-url-rewriting)

Also, you need to edit your application/bootstrap.php and setup the initialization variables there.

```
Kohana::init( array(
'base_url' => '/',
'index_file' => FALSE,
) );
```

You may want to check the user guide, there is a page just for this setup.

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls

Comment: there is also kerkness' brilliant guide (http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=removing_the_index.php) which has a nice little troubleshooting section.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use action_index, action_services and action_contact inside Controller_Index.

If so, all you need to do is remove the controller section from routes (in your bootstrap.php)

```
Route::set('posttype', '<param>', array('action' => 'index|services|contact'))
  ->defaults(array(
  'controller'=> 'index',
  'action' => 'index'
  ));
```